# Jquery ui dialog does not work?

Tags: 7, javascript

In .module file for a function hook_form_alter() I have the following code:

```
  drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.dialog');
        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'abc') . "/custom.js");
```

In .js file I have the following code :

```
var abc = $('#inst').val();
var data = 'Please confirm it';
if (abc == "" ) {
alert(abc);
$("#dialog").html(data);
                    $('#dialog').dialog({
                        modal: true,
                        autoOpen: false,
                        width: 600,
                        buttons: {
                            "Ok": function() {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }}
                    });
                    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
}
                    return false;
                }
```

I am not able to get the dialog whereas I am able to get the alert(abc);
What is the error in the code?

Comment: Let me paraphrase you: What is the error displayed in JavaScript console when you try? Also, any modules like jQuery Update? Last but not least, in `hook_form_alter` use [Form API `#attached`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attached), not `drupal_add_js`.

Comment: Before installing the jquery update i was getting the Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog` errrot

Comment: After I installed the jquery_update module the error disappeared but the dialog does not appear.Pls help?

Comment: I'm using this without a problem: `$('<div>' + Drupal.t('Some fields was left blank even when not disabled. Either check "skip line" or fill missing data.') + '</div>').dialog({ modal: true });` Try direct copy paste first ;)

Comment: Yes that is working so whats the error in my code

Comment: pls let me know why -1 is my question erroneous

Comment: -1 is not from me, I'm pretty much indifferent: It's easy to find on your own ( jqueryui.com/dialog is pretty obvious URL for dialog method in jquery UI pack ) , but well, I made the same mistake and struggled with it before it ever occurred to me to really look :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `dialog` method like simple substitution for `alert`.

```
$(this).dialog("close");
```

But it isn't. It works that way:

```
$( /* DOM node you want to turn into a dialog */ ).dialog( /* dialog options */ );
```

So your code should look like this:

```
$('<p>' + Drupal.t('Close') + '</p>').dialog({ modal: true });
```

Note that you need [jQuery Update](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module, or one of it's substitutes, to have dialog method available. You need jQuery UI version 1.0 or later, and jQuery Update adds 1.8.11 or (in dev branch) 1.10.1 so as long as you have it at all, you don't need to worry.

Full documentation here: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/